# Timesyncd service return (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemd-timesyncd

I am on Ubuntu server 18.04 and the clock do not sync

```
:~$ timedatectl status
                      Local time: jeu. 2022-12-22 09:36:48 CET
                  Universal time: jeu. 2022-12-22 08:36:48 UTC
                        RTC time: n/a
                       Time zone: Europe/Paris (CET, +0100)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Trying to start the service :

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
Job for systemd-timesyncd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Status :

```
 systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-22 09:26:36 CET; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
  Process: 28171 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
 Main PID: 28171 (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
```

I cannot figure out why it does not work

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl show -p NoNewPrivileges systemd-timesyncd.service`? I don't think is relevant but maybe you have property `NoNewPrivileges` to false

Comment: It's set to `yes`